# Symfony FOS UserBundle: override error landing page

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, fosuserbundle

I'm overriding the forms on my Symfony app, but I surely skipped something in the process, but I do not know what.

Basically, it all works fine and looking as I want it to, but as soon as I purposely generate an error(i.e : changing email address to an invalid one), I am redirected to the lonely form template, instead of reloading to my page with the generated and displaying the problem.

I tried replacing this line  :

```
return $this->render('@FOSUser/Profile/edit.html.twig', array(
'form' => $form->createView(),
 ));
```

from the ProfileController, as I think it is the reason, but I'm doing it wrong and getting errors when I try.

What would be the correct syntax to go my customized profile page that contains other forms, while displaying the errors of the submitted form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have already overridden FOSUserBundle by your own UserBundle (as explained in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html)). Then, you have to modify the function `editAction()` in your own `ProfileController`, and write the twig template of your UserBundle profile page (look at my last comment in the code below):

```
<?php
// src/UserBundle/Controller/ProfileController.php

namespace UserBundle\Controller;

// use statements

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Edit the user.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        /** @var $dispatcher EventDispatcherInterface */
        $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        /** @var $formFactory FactoryInterface */
        $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            /** @var $userManager UserManagerInterface */
            $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_SUCCESS, $event);

            $userManager->updateUser($user);

            if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {

                $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
                $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            }

            $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::PROFILE_EDIT_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

            return $response;
        }

        // Change the following line, with your custom profile twig template
        //return $this->render('@FOSUser/Profile/edit.html.twig', array(
        return $this->render('UserBundle:Profile:edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Overriding the controller was the one thing I forgot sigh… haha, now some ajax and I'll get what I want just fine, thanks !